# Material setings in properties window is missing

Tags: materials, interface

I have added a sphere and I was able to add material and give it a color. Now when I add a second sphere (separate object), the material panel is just blank.
[image: blank material settings]

**[Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bgi7lloc0can4l/Spheres.blend?dl=0)**

Comment: We will need some more details I am afraid. A screenshot of your scene and node setup would be ideal.

Comment: Here's the link 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w86k4o08euteake/Blender.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I need to see the material you added, scroll up and select one.

Comment: Here's the link 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8h6mkyu4wwwo88a/MaterialBlender.png?dl=0

it worked for other material as you can see

Comment: [upload a file with the problem on here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  so we can take closer look  ,enough with screenshots : )

Comment: Here's the file :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bgi7lloc0can4l/Spheres.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to scroll up in the properties panel.

Because there is no material on that object, the panel is much shorter. If you had just scrolled down when editing the material on your pink object, then the *New* material button will be off the screen.

[image: animated gif]

Comment: @user13390 glad I could help you. (Don't feel bad, your "dumb" mistake will no doubt help many more people in the future.)

Comment: If scrolling up doesn't work, maybe [the menu was changed to Horizontal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120926/16395)