# Cannot add modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, interface

I am following one of [Quill18's](https://www.youtube.com/user/quill18creates) tutorials for Blender and Unity 3D. I have a very simple model with one object so far and need to add a second object.

The first model has multiple modifiers, the Mirror modifier being one of them. Now, I also need to apply the Mirror modifier to the new object.

Unfortunately, I don't see the option in the interface. When the first object is selected the relevant tab (spanner) exists and contains the correct modifiers and an "Add Modifier" button.

When the new object is selected, the tab also exists, but it is empty (doesn't contain any buttons whatsoever).

How can I add a modifier to the second object?

The .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6iyitaqp68cofen/Level1_2_objects.blend?dl=0

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I use Windows 7 Home Premium on a 64-bit laptop.

Comment: That's very strange. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: @gandalf3 I just did

Comment: I only see one object in that file..?

Comment: @gandalf3 Sorry, the new file should be the correct one.

Comment: Hm.. For me the panel contains the *Add modifier* dropdown even with the cube selected. What version of blender are you using?

Comment: @gandalf3 Added screenshots. I am using Blender v2.75.

Comment: To somebody more familiar with this site and its rules: Should I delete the question, like it would be appropriate for StackOverflow questions which turned out to be typos?

Comment: No, it's completely possible (even probable) that someone else could run into this same problem.

Comment: I think this is the same problem as I answered in [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27671/2217).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your properties panel is scrolled down. Try scrolling up with the mouse wheel or the scroll bar:

[image]

Comment: I've never had this kind of situation with a scroll bar in properties panel. How does it happen?

Comment: @Gonzou Scroll position is remembered between separate objects. So if you are scrolled down on the modifiers section on one object, it will be scrolled the same amount on all other objects (regardless of the number of modifiers etc.) [There was](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-funboard/2015-July/006286.html) a [related discussion](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-funboard/2015-July/006289.html) a while back on the mailing lists..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @gandalf3! BTW I found out, that the quickest way to fix it is pressing the HOME button in the properties window. I've learned one rule about Blender recently: 'Whenever you're lost, remember to press a HOME button' :).

Comment: Lol xD didn't realize my problem was this simple.