# How do I add Add Modifier to the UI

Tags: modifiers, interface

In the online manual it shows a panel with a drop-down for selecting modifiers to add. I can't find that anywhere and no one seems to know anything about it? Is the manual wrong? Does that not exist? Is there a way to make Add Modifiers available via the UI?

https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/introduction.html#interface

[image]

Comment: It should be there.. Is the [panel scrolled down](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33921/599)?

Comment: QUICK TIP: If you want to quickly add a Subdivision Surface modifier to a mesh, press Ctrl+1(from your numerical keyboard). The higher the value the more subdivisions will be displayed. For example: you press Ctrl+3 and you get subdivision lvl 3.

Comment: just not ctrl6
doesn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

In the properties panel you have the tab for the modifiers. If you click on add modifiers you can choose different modifiers

Comment: The manual should really include this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it IS available from the default UI but at some resolutions you may not be able to see it. In the factory default view of the UI, on the right, under the Outline view, there is a bar with some mini icons on it.

Turns out that bar extends to the left and if you have not manipulated your UI, the icon for modifiers is just past the edge of the screen hidden over there past the constraints button, seventh button over. (just like you see above)

I had to grab that panel and pull its edge left thus opening up the panel and lo and behold there it is.