# No settings appearing in the Properties Editor

Tags: modeling, interface

I have the object selected in Object Mode but the Properties Editor is not showing me any settings/options in order to allow me to add textures, modifiers, materials, etc. It's as if nothing is selected yet the object is selected. Switching back and forth between Object and Edit mode makes no difference. Cycles Render is selected. I'm running version 2.79b. I'm thinking its got to be something simple that I'm just overlooking but for the life of me I can't figure out what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material setings in properties window is missing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27671/material-setings-in-properties-window-is-missing)

Comment: put your mouse pointer over the panel, then scroll up!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem. In fact I had somehow changed the menu to horizontal.

Right-clicking on the *Properties* panel and changing it from *Horizontal* to *Vertical* fixed this problem.

[image]

Comment: Nice! It actually looks like you encountered a bug that can be easily reproduced: in fact, even in "Horizontal", the first line should be visible anyway, but it isn't in some circumstances! I'll probably report it